# Windows 7 won't boot after Ubuntu installation

Tags: boot, windows

I know there's multiple threads for this problem, but it seems I've tried everything with no help.  I'll start at the beginning.

My desktop computer is running Windows 7.  I shrank the disc to create a partition for Ubuntu.  I had a installation version of Ubuntu on a USB stick that I then ran.  I created a partition for EFI boot and EXT4 file system.  When I was about to start the installation process, it never did bring up the option to "Install along side Windows."  I didn't think much of it, just selected the option for "Something else" and continued from there.

Long story endless, I can no longer boot to Windows.  I've got the GRUB boot loader, but there's never a menu that pops up.  I've updated Grub thru Terminal.  I've installed Boot Repair and have ran that a few times and selecting a few different options.  If I go into Disk Management, it does recognize the NTFS, so the Windows partitions are still there.

I've got another OS on a USB stick and I can't even boot to the stick, even with the correct settings in BIOS.  Not sure where to go from here.  Thanks for the help.

Here's the boot information:

```
============================= Boot Info Summary: ===============================
```

=> Grub2 (v2.00) is installed in the MBR of /dev/sda and looks at sector 1 of 
    the same hard drive for core.img. core.img is at this location and looks 
    for (,msdos6)/boot/grub. It also embeds following components:

```
modules
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
fshelp ext2 part_msdos biosdisk
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

sda1: __________________________________________________________________________

```
File system:       ntfs
Boot sector type:  Windows 7/2008: NTFS
Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
Operating System:  
Boot files:        /bootmgr /Boot/BCD
```

sda2: __________________________________________________________________________

```
File system:       ntfs
Boot sector type:  Windows 7/2008: NTFS
Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
Operating System:  
Boot files:        /Windows/System32/winload.exe
```

sda3: __________________________________________________________________________

```
File system:       Extended Partition
Boot sector type:  -
Boot sector info:
```

sda5: __________________________________________________________________________

```
File system:       vfat
Boot sector type:  FAT32
Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
Operating System:  
Boot files:        /EFI/ubuntu/grub.cfg /EFI/BOOT/fbx64.efi 
                   /EFI/ubuntu/fwupx64.efi /EFI/ubuntu/grubx64.efi 
                   /EFI/ubuntu/mmx64.efi /EFI/ubuntu/shimx64.efi
```

sda6: __________________________________________________________________________

```
File system:       ext4
Boot sector type:  -
Boot sector info: 
Operating System:  Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS
Boot files:        /boot/grub/grub.cfg /etc/fstab 
                   /boot/grub/i386-pc/core.img
```

Comment: You cannot mix UEFI & BIOS on one drive. Windows requires BIOS boot flag on its boot partition your sda1, but UEFI requires a boot flag on the ESP your sda5. And you only can have one boot flag per drive. Move boot flag back to sda1. Use Boot-Repair in Ubuntu live installer booted in BIOS mode to reinstall grub in BIOS boot mode. Then grub can also boot Windows. Only other alternative is total reinstall of Windows in UEFI boot mode which also requires gpt partitioning.

Comment: How do I change from UEFI to BIOS?

Comment: Another stupid question, while I don't have an option that I can see in the bios menu to change, I did finally get into the Grub menu.  Windows was not on that list.  I typed in exit and then boom, all of sudden it booted Windows.  I haven't a clue on what's going on.

Comment: The process for disabling UEFI usually varies, normally buried somewhere in the bios menu. Regarding the weird mix of grub and Windows, I encountered something like that many years ago. Unsure if that was fixed in Windows 10 or whether I've just been lucky. You might need to repair your master boot record in Windows. If you do that, you could access to your Ubuntu partition again and may need to recreate that as well.

Comment: Microsoft required vendors to allow users to turn off Secure Boot and then allow BIOS boot. Often called "Windows" or "Other", but fine print says if Windows 7 use "Other". Then from boot options should be either UEFI or BIOS/CSM/Legacy boot options. Varies by every vendors implementation of UEFI/BIOS.